# drop down based on a condition in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I need to show a dropdown based on a condition.

Following is the dropdown in the view page. Which list the properties name that being fetched from `property table` where it has a `type status` field, where its value is either `sale` or `lease`.

If property type status is sale then it must display a dropdown with options say `available` and `sold`. And if it is `lease` then `occupied` and `vacancy`.

`property name` and `type status` are inserted in `property form`. condition is to be applied in `unit form`. Where `property name` dropdown is given. And based on that it has to show another dropdown with either `sold and available` or `occupied and vacant`.

I hope my question is clear. I tried to explain it. please help me to do this. thanks in advance

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Property Name<span class="manda">*</span> </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pId" id="property">
        <option value="0">Choose....</option>
        
        <?php
        if ( $property ) {
            
            foreach ( $property as $row ) {
                
                echo "<option value='" . $row->pId . "'>" . $row->name . "</option>";
            }
            
        } ?>

    </select>
    <span class="error invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

when I choose an option from above dropdown say property name, an on-change event takes place.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "document" ).ready( function () {
        $( "#property" ).change( function () {
            var property_id = $( this ).val();
            $.ajax( {
                url: '<?php echo base_url( 'admin/Unit/get_type_status' )?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { property_id: property_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log( response );

                    if ( response == "Sale" ) {
                        $( "#sale" ).show();
                    } else {
                        $( "#lease" ).show();
                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

where it fetches the value that needs to be checked. `console.log(response);` gives `{type_status: "Sale"}`. so I need to check `if(response == "Sale")` I don't know how should I check it. If it so then to display the following code.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Property Status<span class="manda">*</span> </label>
    <div id="sale">
        <select class="form-control" name="typeStatus" id="typeStatus">
            <option value="0">Choose....</option>
            <option value="Available">Available</option>
            <option value="Sold">Sold</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

else need to show following code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Property Status<span class="manda">*</span> </label>
    <div id="lease">
        <select class="form-control" name="typeStatus" id="typeStatus">
            <option value="0">Choose....</option>
            <option value="Occupied">Occupied</option>
            <option value="Vacancy">Vacancy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This isn't working I don't have an idea how to show dropdown based on a condition.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: I mean I didn't get the output as I'm expecting. I know this won't. can u please help me to get to do this.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is an object, not a string. You have to access the property `type_status` to check the value.

Change your script to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "document" ).ready( function () {
        
        const sale = $( "#sale" );
        const lease = $( "#lease" );
        
        // hide both elements at start
        sale.hide();
        lease.hide();
        
        $( "#property" ).change( function () {
            const property_id = $( this ).val();

            $.ajax( {
                url: '<?php echo base_url( 'admin/Unit/get_type_status' )?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { property_id: property_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log( response );
                    
                    // check the property 'type_status'
                    if ( response.type_status == "Sale" ) { 
                        lease.hide();
                        sale.show();
                    } else {
                       sale.hide();
                       lease.show();
                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

And use this HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Property Status<span class="manda">*</span> </label>
    <div id="sale">
        <select class="form-control" name="typeStatus" id="typeStatus">
            <option value="0">Choose....</option>
            <option value="Available">Available</option>
            <option value="Sold">Sold</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="lease">
        <select class="form-control" name="typeStatus" id="typeStatus">
            <option value="0">Choose....</option>
            <option value="Occupied">Occupied</option>
            <option value="Vacancy">Vacancy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```